# h:panelGrid cell color

Tags: html, css, jsf

I am building a table with h:panelGrid. The example I will show is static code but my actual implementation will be in the backing bean which is perhaps not relevant to questions I will ask here. 
So here is what I have:

(I cannot post image!?!? I need 10 reputation!)

Certain cells may have nested h:panelGrid containers with multiple text items. The example is the biggest cell circled in green. Some cells have wider content but some cells have multiple-row content. And finally some cells may have no content at all. The data is fed from DB so not known in design-time.

Questions:
1. Certain empty cells (no data) must have appropriate background color. Circled in red (to the left) is one example. I tried to nest another h:panelGrid with some spacer but no luck:

```
             <h:panelGrid columns="12" id="pg1" border="2">
                <h:panelGrid id="pg2">
                    <h:outputText value="ID" id="ot1"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg3">
                    <h:outputText value="Name" id="ot2"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg4">
                    <h:outputText value="Whatifs" id="ot3"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg5">
                    <h:outputText value="Birth Date" id="ot4" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg6">
                    <h:outputText value="Who" id="ot5" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg7">
                    <h:outputText value="Directed To" id="ot6" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg8">
                    <h:outputText value="Whatever" id="ot7" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg9">
                    <h:outputText value="Whatever One" id="ot8" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg10">
                    <h:outputText value="Whatever Five" id="ot9" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg11">
                    <h:outputText value="Whatever 1" id="ot10" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg12">
                    <h:outputText value="Payment Received" id="ot11" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg13">
                    <h:outputText value="Serious issues" id="ot12" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <!-- 1st subject -->
                <h:panelGrid id="pg1_1">
                    <af:link text="100000:123" id="l1"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg1_2">
                    <h:outputText value="JANE A SMITH" id="ot1_2"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg1_3">
                    <h:outputText value="01/01/2015" id="ot1_3"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg1_4">
                    <h:outputText value="01/08/1980" id="ot1_4" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg1_5">
                    <h:outputText value="F" id="ot1_5" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg1_6" style="background-color:Yellow;">
                    <af:spacer width="10" height="10" id="s1_2" inlineStyle="background-color:Highlight;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg1_7">
                    <af:spacer width="10" height="10" id="s1_3" inlineStyle="background-color:Highlight;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg1_8">
                    <af:spacer width="10" height="10" id="s1_4" inlineStyle="background-color:Highlight;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg1_9">
                    <af:spacer width="10" height="10" id="s1_5" inlineStyle="background-color:Highlight;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg1_10">
                    <af:spacer width="10" height="10" id="s6" inlineStyle="background-color:Highlight;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg1_11">
                    <h:outputText value="Payment For Sure" id="ot1_11" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg1_12" style="background-color:#d6ffd6;">
                    <h:outputText value="Hardtime:Today" id="ot1_12" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                    <h:outputText value="Hardtime:Tomorrow" id="ot1_13" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <!-- 2nd subject -->
                <h:panelGrid id="pg2_1">
                    <af:link text="200000:123" id="l2"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg2_2">
                    <h:outputText value="JASON DOE SMITH" id="ot2_2"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg2_3">
                    <h:outputText value="01/01/2015" id="ot2_3"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg2_4">
                    <h:outputText value="01/03/1980" id="ot2_4" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg2_5">
                    <h:outputText value="M" id="ot2_5" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg2_6" style="background-color:Yellow;" layout="block">
                    <af:spacer width="10" height="10" id="s2_1" inlineStyle="background-color:Highlight;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg2_7" style="background-color:#d6ffd6;">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="pg14">
                        <h:outputText value="Proposals" id="ot2_51" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                        <h:outputText value="Frank Doe:Completed Issue" id="ot2_52"
                                      style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="pg15">
                            <h:outputText value="Hardline Test" id="ot2_53"/>
                            <h:outputText value="IQ Test" id="ot2_54"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg2_8">
                    <af:spacer width="10" height="10" id="s4" inlineStyle="background-color:Highlight;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg2_9">
                    <af:spacer width="10" height="10" id="s5" inlineStyle="background-color:Highlight;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg2_10">
                    <af:spacer width="10" height="10" id="s7" inlineStyle="background-color:Highlight;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg2_11">

                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="pg2_12" style="background-color:#d6ffd6;">
                    <h:outputText value="Individual Not Smart Enough Today" id="ot2_12" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>

                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGrid>
```

2. Second problem: For the widest or tallest cell's content in the column or row, I can apply full background color: This is one cell example (nested panelGrids)

```
<h:panelGrid id="pg2_7" style="background-color:#d6ffd6;">
<h:panelGrid columns="3" id="pg14">
<h:outputText value="Proposals" id="ot2_51" style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
<h:outputText value="Frank Doe:Completed Issue" id="ot2_52"
                                              style="text-wrap:avoid;"/>
<h:panelGrid columns="1" id="pg15">
<h:outputText value="Hardline Test" id="ot2_53"/>
<h:outputText value="IQ Test" id="ot2_54"/>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

However if the cell's data (some text) next to it (to the right or left) or below or above it, is of less width or height, then the background color will only be applied behind the text, and leave remaining of the cell transparent.

So how in the world to apply the background to certain cell, (NOT entire column, NOT entire row just cell) regardless of its content?